# Why is awk command not working in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, awk, sh

I wrote a shell script which uses `awk` command in it.

It used to work before as expected. It stopped working very recently and throwing `awk command not found` error when running the script

```
#!/bin/bash

SRCDIR="/home/ubuntu/imdb/src"
DATADIR="/home/ubuntu/imdb/data"
PATH="/home/ubuntu/imdb/data/tmp"

split_cst_data()
{
    echo "krishna"
    data=`awk 'END {print NR}' $DATADIR/data_cst_name_basics.tsv`
    echo $data
    #l_upto=$((data / 100)
    #split -l$l_upto data_cst_name_basics.tsv $PATH/split_file_
    
}
split_cst_data
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> krishna
>
> ./test_imdb_cst.sh: line 12: awk: command not found

Comment: I was messing with *PATH* variable which I realised later. It worked after renaming it.

Comment: This is why you should stick to lower- and mixed-case variable names. `PATH` is a common mistake, but there are too many all-caps names with special meaning to keep track of them all.